# Entity Framework .NET Core issue

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I'm trying to figure out this why this entity code is not working. When I call the following code,

```
await _context.ApplicationUsers
                .Include(u => u.SentFriendRequests)
                .Include(u => u.ReceievedFriendRequests)
                .Include(u => u.Friends)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync()
```

I get a message

> Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid

when I include `Friends`. Another weird issue if I don't include the friends property, it finds the list of friends, but each item only has RequestedBy object and all RequestedTo users are null. It only finds the RequestedToId.

Here's the code:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser

public ApplicationUser()
{
    SentFriendRequests = new List<Friend>();
    ReceievedFriendRequests = new List<Friend>();
}

public string Name { get; set; }

public ICollection<Friend> SentFriendRequests { get; set; }
public ICollection<Friend> ReceievedFriendRequests { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public ICollection<Friend> Friends
{
    get
    {
        var friends = SentFriendRequests.Where(x => x.Approved).ToList();
        friends.AddRange(ReceievedFriendRequests.Where(x => x.Approved));
        return friends;
    }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<FriendRequest>()
                .HasKey(t => new { t.RequestedById, t.RequestedToId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Friend>()
        .HasOne(a => a.RequestedBy)
        .WithMany(b => b.SentFriendRequests)
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.RequestedById);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Friend>()
        .HasOne(a => a.RequestedTo)
        .WithMany(b => b.ReceievedFriendRequests)
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.RequestedToId);
}

public class Friend
{
    public int RequestedById { get; set; }
    public int RequestedToId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser RequestedBy { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser RequestedTo { get; set; }

    public FriendRequestFlag FriendRequestFlag { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public bool Approved => FriendRequestFlag == FriendRequestFlag.Approved;
}

public enum FriendRequestFlag
{
    New,
    Approved,
    Rejected,
    Blocked,
    Spam
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the first issue is that your Friends collection is NotMapped, therefore, you can't add it to an Include Statement since EFCore doesn't know/care about the property (Which is what you wanted by adding NotMapped).

Your second problem is that when you do an "Include", it's only one level deep. If you have navigational properties on that object, you need to keep going. For example :

```
await _context.ApplicationUsers
    .Include(u => u.SentFriendRequests)
    .ThenInclude(u => u.RequestedTo)//This is in the context of SendFriendRequests
    .Include(u => u.ReceievedFriendRequests)
    .ThenInclude(u => u.RequestedTo)//This is in the context of ReceivedFriendRequests
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync()
```

The problem you are going to find is that, you will have to pre-define how deep you want your connections to go (Since you have what looks to be a recursive type model).

It's probably better to instead create a DTO and select out exactly what you need so then you don't do an overselect.

Comment: That was it! Thank you for your help and explanation.